# Vim filetype detecting

Tags: vim

Can Vim detect filetype of a buffer with contents, but which doesn't have a name yet (not yet saved)? `:filetype detect` doesn't do much.

Answer (score 5):

Most filetypes are detected by their file name (and/or location), some (mostly those with a `#!` shebang line) by their contents.

If you don't want to save the buffer yet, but have detection, you can name the buffer via `:file name.ext`. Then, the detection via `:filetype detect` will work.

If you just want syntax highlighting (and corresponding filetype settings) quickly, just manually set the filetype via `:setf name`.

Comment: Yeah. The thing is I'm mainly interested in fortran filetype, which has (under that name) two variants - modern and the other one. And which one gets choosen depends on some variables pre-set, which depend on (haven't got a clue on what they depend on). So simply choosing a filetype doesn't really work for me. I need Vim to do it.  And I'm trying to avoid naming the file.

Comment: Okay, now you're mixing two things. The detection of unsaved buffer should have been answered. For Fortran variants, it seems that Vim already has elaborate detection; read up on `:help ft-fortran-syntax`. If that still doesn't suit you, you have to write / extend the detection, cp. `:help new-filetype-scripts`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this manually.

```
:set filetype=EXT
```

Note that EXT is the extension for the filetype you want, not necessarily the name of the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the help for `vim` says, it works in some cases, for instance if you type

```
#!/bin/sh
```

then it will detect as `sh` script.

Comment: Does not; I'm asking for ft detection in general.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains a `#!` on line one it's easy.

For example:

```
" finish if the filetype was detected
if did_filetype()
    finish
endif

" Ruby & Python ftplugins
if getline(1) =~ '^#!.*ruby'
    setfiletype ruby
elseif getline(1) =~ '^#!.*python'
    setfiletype python
endif
```

Comment: Does not; I'm asking for ft detection in general.